# asp.net mvc razor: How to directly access .cshtml page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

How can i directly access a .cshtml file in ASP.NET MVC using razor view engine?

For example i have this url: localhost/Home/About. This will load the about site inside the "master" page.

I want to load the about page without also loading the master page. So i was thinking that i could use this url: localhost/Home/About.cshtml. But it's not working.

How can i load a view page without loading the master page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the method [`Html.Partial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.partialextensions.partial%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) like this:

`@Html.Partial("About")`

**Edit**

I might have missunderstood your question. If you want to avoid including the master page you need to remove the layout.

Add this to the top of your View:

```
@{
     Layout = null;
 }
```

Comment: No i have allready put in Layout = null in my Views. I don't want to view master page at all. Should i place the @Html.Partial in the View?

Comment: No, `@Html.Partial` is just for including bits and pieces. What does your controller return? And what does your View look like? What is at the top of the View?