# IIS Missing MIME cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, razor

When I run my application locally ( VS2013 installed ) everything works fine, but when I deploy the files to another server with only basic IIS installed I get missing CSHTML missing.

Error details:

```
 HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
 The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

 Module
 StaticFileModule 

 Notification
 ExecuteRequestHandler 

 Handler
 StaticFile 

 Error Code
 0x80070032 

 Requested URL
 http://localhost:80/myapp/Default.cshtml 

 Physical Path
 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\Default.cshtml 

 Logon Method
 Anonymous 

 Logon User
 Anonymous
```

...if I add the MIME type it literally just renders some text of my razor view.

I feel like I'm missing some root dependency in my nuget packages that are deployed that is installed by vs out of the box.

My project references look like: http://www.screencast.com/t/BKoB4MSWX and http://www.screencast.com/t/NOOMxD3sYn ... anyone know what im missing?

*Updates:*
No MVC components are installed, I'm not using any MVC just this one page is cshtml.  I also don't have any razor dependencies installed at the moment.  My app is targeted at .net 4.5.1 .  I'm using IIS 7.5.  App pool is integrated 4.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: It's probably more likely that IIS isn't set up correctly to run an MVC application. Which version of IIS? Which version of MVC are you using? Which version of .NET is the application pool tied to your application using? Which version of the .NET framework is your project targeting?

Comment: @Cory updated comments to include your questions

Comment: you are using IIS6.1 then which OS are you using? @amcdnl

Comment: @Rezoan Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: are you sure it has IIS 6.1? @amcdnl

Comment: @Rezoan im stupid ... 7.5

Comment: :) no problem. its ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably that you have Razor dependencies in your GAC, but when you deploy they are not there on the remote server.

Install the Web Pages package: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages`

You might be missing more things, but that's the minimal starting point

Comment: After doing that I still get same error message... :(

Comment: Did you deploy the package to the server? checkout your bin folder on the server, what does it contain? (and what version of .NET are you running on the server, I noticed 4.5.1 on the client but can you verify the server version?) And last what is the URL you are using?

Comment: is myapp an application or just a folder on your remote IIS?

Comment: I noticed cshtml was set to System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler in httphandlers

Comment: I did not deploy the package.  Web Platform said 4.5.1 is installed.

Comment: 1. You have to deploy the package :) Make sure it shows up on the remote servers application bin folder.

Comment: Ended up being a registry issue after I installed that package, running `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -ir` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

[IIS returns 404 for ASP.NET MVC3 file (.cshtml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366925/iis-returns-404-for-asp-net-mvc3-file-cshtml?rq=1)

Enable `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests`:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Hmm.. sorry - don't know what else. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check if ‘CSHTML’ is mapped in IIS Manager. From IIS Manager, select the site you want to add the MIME to from the Connections left pane,
In the Home pane, double-click MIME Types.
In the MIME Types pane, click Add... in the Actions pane.
    mimeMap fileExtension=".cshtml" mimeType="application/x-cshtml" 
Alternatively, you could use the conf file applicationHost.conf C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config:
•   And running from command: aspnet_regiis –iru
•   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -iru